# Is it possible to change the whole background colour in console?

Tags: vb.net

I can change the background of the text using

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
Console.WriteLine("This is blue")
```

However I would like to know if it is possible to change the background of the whole console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Console.Clear, as follows:

```
   Sub Main()

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White

        '' the entire console will now be white on dark blue
        Console.Clear()

        Console.WriteLine("Test")

        Console.Read()

    End Sub
```

Comment: If this answers your question, can you please mark it as the correct answer?  Thanks!